# Trying to write a query that will display authors and their publications even authors that have no publications

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    SELECT a.auth_name AS 'NAME', p.pub_title AS 'PUBLICATION'
    FROM publication p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN author_publication d
    ON p.pub_id = d.pub_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT a.auth_name 
    FROM author a,author_publication d
    WHERE a.auth_id = d.auth_id);
    GO
```

AND GET THE ERROR
        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
        Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: THERE IS NO NEED TO YELL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an ON clause after that last outer join to the subquery.  However, you probably don't want a subquery at all.  I'm guessing you want this:

```
SELECT a.auth_name AS 'NAME', p.pub_title AS 'PUBLICATION'
FROM publication p
LEFT OUTER JOIN author_publication d
    ON p.pub_id = d.pub_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN author a 
    ON d.auth_id = a.auth_id
```

Hard to be sure without knowing your database

Answer (score 0):

change it like this:

```
 SELECT a.auth_name AS 'NAME',d.auth_id, p.pub_title AS 'PUBLICATION' FROM publication p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
     author_publication d
    ON p.pub_id = d.pub_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    author as a 
    on a.auth_id = d.auth_id
```

or

```
SELECT a.auth_name AS 'NAME', c.pub_title AS 'PUBLICATION' FROM
(select p.pub_title AS 'PUBLICATION' from
(select * from  publication) as p
left outer join
(select * from author_publication) as d
ON p.pub_id = d.pub_id)as c
left outer join
(SELECT a.auth_name FROM author a) as a 
on ON p.pub_id = c.pub_id
```